# What is angle brackets for argument values, and what is it used for?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

I am used to angle brackets being used to specify a type, as a parameter:

```
vector<int> vecOfInts ;
```

But in [rapidjson](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson), there is code like this:

```
document.Parse<0>(json) ;
```

The `document.Parse` method's signature is:

```
template <unsigned parseFlags>
GenericDocument& Parse(const Ch* str) {
    RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(!(parseFlags & kParseInsituFlag));
    GenericStringStream<Encoding> s(str);
    return ParseStream<parseFlags>(s);
}
```

I didn't know you could pass a *value* inside angle brackets - thought angle brackets were used for typenames alone.

What is the code here doing, and why is he passing a *value* in the angle brackets?

Is this a good idea?  When?

Comment: Look up "non-type template parameter".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two different factors going on here.

First, it's possible to define templates that are parameterized over things other than just types.  For example, here's a simple array type:

```
template <typename T, size_t N> struct Array {
    T arr[N];
};
```

We can use this like

```
Array<int, 137> myArray;
```

We know that `vector<int>` and `vector<double>` are different types. But now we must also point out that `Array<int,137>` and `Array<int,136>` are different types.

Second, when using templates, the compiler has to be able to figure out a value for all of the template arguments.  When you're using template classes, this is why you typically specify all the template arguments.  You don't say `vector x`, for example, but instead say something like `vector<double> x`.  When using template functions, most of the time the compiler can figure out the arguments.  For example, to use `std::sort`, you just say something like

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

However, you could also write

```
std::sort<vector<int>::iterator>(v.begin(), v.end());
```

to be more explicit.  But sometimes, you have a template function for which not all the arguments can be figured out.  In your example, we have this:

```
template <unsigned parseFlags>
GenericDocument& Parse(const Ch* str) {
    RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(!(parseFlags & kParseInsituFlag));
    GenericStringStream<Encoding> s(str);
    return ParseStream<parseFlags>(s);
}
```

Notice that the `parseFlags` template parameter can't be deduced from just the arguments of the function.  As a result, to call the function, you *must* specify the template parameter, since otherwise the compiler can't figure it out.  That's why you'd write something like

```
Parse<0>(myString);
```

Here, the 0 is a template argument (resolved at compile-time), and `myString` is the actual argument (resolved at run-time).

You can actually have methods that combine a bit of type inference and a bit of explicit type parameters.  For example, in Boost, there's a function `lexical_cast` that can do conversions to and from string types.  The function signature to convert from a non-string type to a string type is

```
template <typename Target, typename Source>
    Target lexical_cast(const Source& arg);
```

Here, if you call `lexical_cast`, the compiler can figure out what `Source` is, but it can't deduce `Target` without some hints.  To use `lexical_cast`, therefore, you'd write something like

```
std::string myString = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(toConvertToString);
```

More generally, the compiler says that you have to specify some number of template arguments (optionally 0), and it will try to deduce the rest.  If it can, great!  If not, it's a compile-time error.  Using this, if you'd like, you could write a function like

```
template <int IntArgument, typename TypeArgment>
    void DoSomething(const TypeArgument& t) {
       /* ... */
}
```

To call this function, you'd have to invoke it like this:

```
DoSomething<intArg>(otherArg);
```

Here, this works because you have to explicitly tell the compiler what `IntArgument` is, but then the compiler can deduce `TypeArgument` from the type of the argument to `DoSomething`.

Hope this helps!